# javaScript jQuery function, how do i pass variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

What is wrong with my code. How do i pass attrfull to the inside. The way i have it done, if i run the function `editsubmit($selected, size)`, $selected is inserted properly but i'm getting  attrfull instead of size.

```
function editsubmit(attr, attrfull) {
    if (attr.length) {
        attr.val().length ? $selectedinput.attr({
            attrfull: attr.val()
        }) : $selectedinput.removeAttr(attrfull);
    }
}
```

$selected is a variable and attrfull i a string. Do i need double qoutes around the string when i run the function like `editsubmit($selected,'size')`.

Comment: Just a thought, but try this: `attr(attrfull, attr.val())`. Should work...

Comment: Yes, single quotes or double quotes around the literal strings.

Comment: I think you should post the code that creates your editsubmit call.  It looks like you're using PHP to generate the JS call...which is fine...but we need to see how you construct the edit submit call.

Comment: `attr.val()` is the not the issue and i'm not using any php. This is a simple function. The only problem i'm having is attrfull is not being passed in to the attrfull that i have inside the function. So if i have editsubmit($var, 'size'), i'm expecting every reference to attrfull inside the function to be replaced with size. But this is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function editsubmit(attr, attrfull) {
    if (attr.length) {
        attr.val().length ? $selectedinput.attr(attrfull, attr.val()) : $selectedinput.removeAttr(attrfull);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you do need it to be a string (in double quotes), or else it will think you're trying to pass a variable reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:
{attrfull: attr.val()}

I think you want it to be
{size: (whatever attr.val() is)}

So:

```
function editsubmit(attr, attrfull) {
    if (attr.length) {
        if (attr.val().length) {
          var myObj = {};
          myObj[attrfull] = attr.val();
          $selectedinput.attr(myObj);
        } else {
          $selectedinput.removeAttr(attrfull);
        }
    }
}
```